# Can't find key in dict?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary in `python 3` with objects in the values, in the form of:

```
a={'modem0': <interfaces.modems.hw_trx_qmi.QmiModem object at 0x7fdcfe9ced70>,
   ...
   ...
  }
```

if I search for the key `modem0` it is not being found, why might this be?

```
if 'modem0' in a:
    print("found")
else: 
    print("not found")
```

Comment: there seems to be an 'invalid syntax' error. try to put that values in a string.

Comment: That's quite interesting. I couldn't replicate it unfortunately though. Maybe there could be any hint in dict __contain__ implementation https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/dictobject.c#L3186

Comment: Are you sure it is a dict object because can't  reproduce in Python 3.11. https://imgur.com/a/DehyQME

Answer (score 0):

```
a={'modem0': "<interfaces.modems.hw_trx_qmi.QmiModem object at 0x7fdcfe9ced70>"}
key_to_lookup = 'modem0'
if a.has_key(key_to_lookup):
   print "Key exists"
else:
   print "Key does not exist"
```

The value of the dictionary is not supported, whatever that format was supposed to be, so wrap it in quotes and parse it if you need it later. Also try using the has_key function like above.

Comment: you can read more about looking up dict keys here, they also provide an interactive environment to each example

https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-check-if-a-key-exists-in-a-python-dictionary

Comment: Hi Mihai, that is python 2 code and doesn't work in python 3 - deprecation, funnily enough my code works fine in python 2 and everything works perfectly in python 3 apart from querying the keys. Really strange.

Comment: hmm, strange indeed. will come with a followup if I find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I would use `get("modem0")` method. Is like using `a["modem0"]` but returning `None` instead of an error if the key doesn't exist and it's value if it does.

```
a={'modem0': <interfaces.modems.hw_trx_qmi.QmiModem object at 0x7fdcfe9ced70>,
   ...
   ...
}
if a.get("modem0") is None:
    print('not found')
else:
    print('found')
```